# Is the watermarkedtextbox in silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I have an old demo project I am trying to dust off to run in Silverlight 3 and it cracks around the "Watermarkedtextbox" element. Anyone know how to get that back, or do I have to come up with another "cool" effect to get the water-mark effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It lives and is built in still! But under a different name.

In the **System.Windows.Controls assembly** actually (in the Silverlight 2 and Silverlight 3 SDKs), in the System.Windows.Controls.Primitives namespace, is the "DatePickerTextBox" class.

This is actually the original WatermarkedTextBox, **renamed**, since it was only tested for primary use in the DatePicker control for now.

More information on the control is available in the [DatePickerTextBox class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datepickertextbox(VS.95).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: would have up-voted, but I can not until I get more reputation...anyway...thank you for the answer. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

Tim Heuer blogged about it a while back: [Silverlight 2 Watermarked TextBox Control](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/22/silverlight-watermark-text-box-control.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the source for the WatermarkedTextBox element from [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/22/silverlight-watermark-text-box-control.aspx).  You can compile it, and then include the resulting DLL in your project, and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `WatermarkedTextBox` was [removed in Silverlight 2 Beta 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/kathykam/archive/2008/06/23/watermarkedtextbox-for-silverlight-2-beta-2.aspx). I believe a similar effect can be achieved using the [`Background`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(VS.95).aspx) property and an appropriate [`Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush(VS.95).aspx).